# Calling view controller method from delegate class, having issues

Tags: iphone, appdelegate

I am calling view controller method from delegate class, the method is called but uitableview declared in that method does not call it delegate methods and a buttons and view also alloc in that view but nothing is shown.

Explaining from begining:

On navigation controller needed a button and to be shown on all views. So, i took that in delegate this way.

```
UIButton *btnMenuOpen = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnMenuOpen.frame = CGRectMake(0, 15, 40, 56);
[btnMenuOpen setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"side_menu.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnMenuOpen addTarget:self action:@selector(menu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.window addSubview:btnMenuOpen];

-(void)menu
{
ViewController *viewC = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[viewC menu];
}
```

This is the view controller class:

```
-(void)menu
{
NSLog(@"menu opened");

self.mMenuView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 480)];
self.mMenuView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
self.mMenuView.autoresizingMask = 0;
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.mMenuView];

self.mSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 16, 220, 44)];
self.mSearchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.mSearchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"slide_tab_button.png"];
self.mSearchBar.delegate = self;
[self.mMenuView addSubview:self.mSearchBar];

UIButton *btnMenuClose = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnMenuClose.frame = CGRectMake(215, 19, 40, 44);
[btnMenuClose setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"side_menu.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnMenuClose addTarget:self action:@selector(menu_close) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.mMenuView addSubview:btnMenuClose];

self.mMenuTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 61,
                                                                   240, 420) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.mMenuTableView.delegate = self;
self.mMenuTableView.dataSource = self;
[self.mMenuView addSubview:self.mMenuTableView];

[self.mMenuTableView reloadData];

}
```

Now, nothing is displyed when this method is called, control goes through it but nothing happens, no delegates of table are called and neither other stuff works(button searchbar and uiview).

Please guide for the above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: all of this code is called in your AppDelegate.m class?

Comment: No in view controller class menu method

Comment: Does your UIViewController implement UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate?

Comment: Why do you alloc and init your table view in the menu method? You can try to alloc and instance in your viewDidLoad method and hide and show the table when you want to show/hide

Comment: I am using two tableviews, one is in viewdidload and second in this methhod this will be shown on uiview declared here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use of `NSNotificationCenter` like this

Register Notification in your ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(menu)
                                                 name: @"myMenuNotification"
                                               object: nil];
}
```

And in your AppDelegate.m call that method using notification like

```
-(void)menu
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myMenuNotification" object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are using. But I have checked code with some modification. it is working fine.
Your modified code is:

In AppDelegate method.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[sampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"sampleViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIButton *btnMenuOpen = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnMenuOpen.frame = CGRectMake(0, 15, 40, 56);
    [btnMenuOpen setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnMenuOpen addTarget:self action:@selector(menu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.window addSubview:btnMenuOpen];

    [self menu];
    return YES;
}

-(void)menu
{
    [self.viewController menu];
}
```

//In view Controller............

```
    -(void)menu
{
    NSLog(@"menu opened");

    UIView *mMenuView;
    UISearchBar *mSearchBar;
    UITableView *mMenuTableView;

    mMenuView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 480)];
    mMenuView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    mMenuView.autoresizingMask = 0;
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:mMenuView];

    mSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 16, 220, 44)];
    mSearchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    mSearchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.jpg"];
//    mSearchBar.delegate = self;
    [mMenuView addSubview:mSearchBar];

    UIButton *btnMenuClose = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnMenuClose.frame = CGRectMake(215, 19, 40, 44);
    [btnMenuClose setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"side_menu.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnMenuClose addTarget:self action:@selector(menu_close) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [mMenuView addSubview:btnMenuClose];

    mMenuTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 61, 240, 420) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
//    mMenuTableView.delegate = self;
//    mMenuTableView.dataSource = self;
    [mMenuTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [mMenuView addSubview:mMenuTableView];

    [mMenuTableView reloadData];
}
```

Screenshot [image: Your App Screenshot]

Comment: One thing i want to ask how to hide/unhide btnMenuOpen button. It can be hidden when method called in delegate but how to unhide it, i mean from where.

Comment: I am not able to understand your question pls explain

Comment: The btnMenuOpen is in delegate when it is clicked this tableview is opened like in above screenshot. The image of that button is still showing, that should be hidden and there is a button immediately after searchbar that hides this view when clicked and then the btnMenuOpen should again be unhide or else we can say that the menu btn should be behind the view not on front as now showing.

Comment: set buttonMenuOpen.tag=5  in menu method in viewController      UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)[self.window viewWithTag:5];
    btn.hidden=true;

Comment: i didn't get please explain.

Comment: self.window not allowed in view controller, i tried with self.view, it doesn't work then.

Comment: UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:5];
    btn.hidden=FALSE;

Comment: btnMenuOpen is in delegate not in viewcontroller.

Comment: self.view.window now got it? Or need to explain more.